# how to isinstance(x, module)?

Tags: python

I need to test if a variable is a module or not. How to do this in the cleanest way?

I need this for initializing some dispatcher function and I want that the function can accept either dict or module as an argument.

Comment: Also, do you really need to check the type of the argument? If the function does something totally different based on which kind of argument it gets, then sure, you have to check, but otherwise it's usually more "Pythonic" not to check types explicitly.

Comment: The pythonic way is to check for the presence of methods and variables. If there are too many to be checked, then isinstance is preferred.

Comment: Well, the Pythonic way is to "check" by just using the ones you need, and if something that should exist doesn't, Python raises an error. I don't see how there could be too many properties to "check" if you're going to use them all anyway.

Comment: There is some software that expects that user will provide his own functions.
imho, the most natural way is to define them as a module and pass it.
However, i'd like to pass a simple dictionary with supplied functions.

And so, I need a wrapper for this.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
>>> import os, types
>>> isinstance(os, types.ModuleType)
True
```

(It also works for your own Python modules, as well as built-in ones like `os`.)

Answer (score 6):

I like to use this so you don't have to import the types module:

```
isinstance(amodule, __builtins__.__class__)
```

Comment: Strange, this worked for me in a script but didn't work deeper in another module.  Perhaps it has some limits?  The chosen answer does work in both cases however.

Comment: Also notes that `__builtins__` is an implementation detail that may not be reliable across Python implementations. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/builtins.html